# Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object

Tags: exception, ssis, jet

I'm reading shapefiles from a file location, reading their metadata and writing them in the database in a SSIS package.

The SSIS packages work on my local machine successfully. I deployed the same SQL job on the server box and when I run the job on the server box (running under a SSIS Executor proxy), it throws me an OLEDB exception:

> The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'tmp5330'.
>   Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path
>   name correctly.

Its definitely happening on the script component where I read the shapefile from a file location and process the metadata. I've double checked that the SSIS account has permissions on the file location (the last folder where the files sit) and it definitely has read permissions on it.

Would be great if someone could help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in the configuration of the Jet Engine, it looks like the it does not accept the files longer than eight characters:

to fix that: 'rename the file so that it matches the MS-DOS 8.3 file name format. That is, the file name must be no more than eight characters in length, and it must have a correct extension following the period, such as .dbf for a dBASE file.'

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209685 for more details.

Comment: Thanks. That's what the problem was. I tried with only one shapefile with less than 8 character long and it seems to be working. I need to check the server now and how Jet is configured.